# Prove that a closed ball in $R^2$ a Borel set

Tags: measure-theory

The definition of the Borel sigma-algebra that I am using is: the sigma algbera generated by the Cartesian products of open intervals in R.

I need to show that the closed ball with center 0 and radius 1 is a Borel set.

I know that I should show that this closed ball can be expressed as a countable union/ intersection of sets of the generating class.

But I don't know how to do so. Please help!

EDIT: I know how to prove it for an open ball. Because then for every point, there is an open rectangle within the ball that has rational endpoints. But what do I do about the boundaries?

Comment: Hint: The set of rational numbers is countable.

Comment: @MitchellSpector I have edited the question. Please see!

Comment: If you use your method to show that the complement of the ball is Borel, can you conclude from that that the ball itself is Borel?

Comment: @MitchellSpector Yes! Thanks!